# Indexing data from multiple data sources (CSV, RDBMS)

Tags: indexing, solr, multiple-databases, dataimporthandler, solrconfig

we are working on indexing data from multiple data sources using a single collection, for that specified data sources information in the **data-config** file and also updated **managed-schema.xml** by adding the fields from all the data sources by specifying the common **unique key** across all the sources.

Here is a sample config file.

```
  <entity >


  </entity> 

 </document>
```

> Blockquote

***Error Details***:
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.RuntimeException:
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Invalid type for data source: Jdbc-2
Processing Document #1

Comment: The error message is telling you that the type you've set up for one of the entries is not valid - i.e. `jdbc-2` is not a valid type. You can leave drop the `type=""` attribute for JDBC entries, since it's the default (and the full type name is `JdbcDataSource`).

Comment: Even we tried that too, but it's not working.

Could you please let us know, if there are any alternative methods or steps to index the data from multiple data sources, and to import the csv, xml, json data to solr ?

Your help will be highly appreciated!!!

Thanking you.

Comment: The best way is to write your own indexing code that submits content to Solr through its regular `/update` handler. That will be more efficient and far more customizable than using DIH.